# Poisson Process E[M(x)*M(x+y)]

Tags: expectation, poisson-distribution

If M(x) where x is greater or equal to 0 is Poisson with rate lambda, what is E[M(x)*M(x+y)]?

I believe the problem can be solved as follows. Please confirm if my invoking of the ind. increments and stationary properties are correct:

$M(x+y) = M(x) + M(x+y) - M(x)$, due to the independent increments property. This is basically breaking up $M(x+y)$ into two intervals, [0,x] and (x,x+y].

$E[M(x)*M(x+y)]$

$= E[M(x)*(M(x)+M(x+y)-M(x))]$

$= E[M(x)^2] + E[M(x)*(M(x+y)-M(x))]$

$= E[M(x)^2] + E[M(x)*M(y)]$ due to stationary property can subtract M(x) from M(x+y)

Due to the stationarity property both M(x) and M(y) are Poisson with rate lambda per unit time.

I am looking at my textboox and $E[M(x)^2]$ is written as:
$lambda*x + (lambda*x)^2$ and I don't see why that is.

The full answer given is:
$lambda*x + (lambda*x)^2 + lambda*x*lambda*y$

I don't see why there are three terms, and in particular I don't see why we have the first two (I am clear about the third one).

Most importantly, is the following correct about the stationary and independent increments property:
*Are the independent increments and stationary properties (or just one or the other) the ones that allow you to do the following?:
$M(x+y) = M(x)+M(x+y)-M(x))$ and then further $M(x+y)-M(x)=M(y)$?

Comment: $E[M(x)^2]= var M(x) + (E[M(x)])^2 = \lambda x + (\lambda x)^2$.

Comment: Yes thank you, I actually figured that a little while after posting. Going back to the stationary and independent increments properties...

Comment: Regarding my main question at the bottom, it appears that only the stationary increments property allows you to proceed with those expressions. My question has been answered. Thank you all.